# SQL Server, SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my application, I am reading email coming from Outlook. After fetching email body i am inserting the email body(html content) in Database. While working on SQLServer-2008R2, some extra  
 tags are getting appended throughout the content , thus making my email body distorted when i am viewing it from front end(application). But if i am using other SQL database, its working fine. I have checked the entire code for any addition of tags, but no such code is present in the application. Do i need to modify some Database level settings? Please help

Comment: Can you clarify/show what exactly  *"some extra 
tags are getting appended throughout the content"* means?

Comment: Can you say a sample of your data.

Comment: Normal email body is -<head>
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */

But after insertion , <br> tag is getting appended-
<head><br><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)"><br> <style><!--<br> /* Font Definitions */<br>

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing in SQL Server 2008 (or any other version) that modifies html inserted into a varchar field. I think you are going to need to post some of the code that inserts the html to the database, and also what retrieves it and renders it on your webpage in order for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Alex and Mehdi- Will this much content help you? You can see <br> tags getting added. In the same manner, its being appended throughout the email body

Comment: As has been said, SQL Server will not insert a "<br>" tag, it does not even know what one is.

Comment: As told by Alex, I again compared both the databases and i found that in the database where i am getting <br> tags, a trigger is present which is replacing char(13) with <br>. So now its resolved. Took 1 day to identify the issue. Thanks a lot everyone.